# Can't call function from within keyDown event handler in ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, function, typeerror, addeventlistener, onkeydown

I'm returning to a slideshow app I was working on last year. I've got prevSlide and nextSlide functions set up so the [trigger upon button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoIuY.jpg) but I also want to support arrow key navigation (And possibly mobile screen swipe functionality in the future).

I set up ComponentDidMount/ComponentDidUnmount functions to register keyDown support for my handleKeyDown event handlers and my handleKeyDownRight event handler works if I just have it triggering the [alert text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFPpJ.jpg). Unfortunately, if I try to call my nextSlide function from within the handleKeyDownRight function, React throws the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLLEU.jpg): "TypeError: this.nextSlide is not a function".

What adjustments can I make to have handleKeyDownRight trigger nextSlide() as pressing the "next" button does?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../Cantiche.scss';

import Card from '../Card/Card';
import data from '../../../data/data';

class Inferno extends Component {
        state = {
          book: data.inferno,
          slide: data.inferno[0]
        }

        componentDidMount = () => {
          window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDownRight);
        }

        prevSlide = () => {
          const newIndex = this.state.slide.index-1;
          this.setState({
            slide: data.inferno[newIndex]
          })
        }

      nextSlide = () => {
        const newIndex = this.state.slide.index+1;
        this.setState({
          slide: data.inferno[newIndex]
        })
      }

      handleKeyDownRight(event) {
        if(event.keyCode === 39){
          alert('Right arrow key');
          this.nextSlide(); //Throws error: "TypeError: this.nextSlide is not a function"
        }
      }

      componentWillUnmount = () => {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handleKeyDownRight);
      }

    render () {
        const {slide} = this.state;

        let cards = (
            <div className={`cards-slider active-slide-${slide.index}`} >
              <div className="cards-slider-wrapper" style={{
                'transform': `translateX(-${slide.index*(100/this.state.book.length)}%)`
              }}>
                {
                  this.state.book.map(slide => <Card key={slide._id} slide={slide} />)
                }
              </div>
            </div>
        )

        return (
            <div className="card-container">
              <h1>Inferno</h1>
              <div className="buttons" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDownRight}>
                <button 
                  onClick={() => this.prevSlide()} 
                  disabled={slide.index === 0}
                >Prev</button>
                <button 
                  onClick={() => this.nextSlide()} 
                  disabled={slide.index === data.inferno.length-1}
                >Next</button>
              </div>
              {cards}
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Inferno;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to write `hadleKeyDownRight` as a arrow function, so it will be bonded to your component like other functions like this:

```
  handleKeyDownRight = (event) => {
    if(event.keyCode === 39){
      alert('Right arrow key');
      this.nextSlide(); //Throws error: "TypeError: this.nextSlide is not a function"
    }
```

You don't have to register event listeners in React. It will be handled by React and besides that, events in React work differently. About that, you can read in docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

If it doesn't help you, please write in the comment what went wrong.

Comment: @Andy you're welcome, in these cases, you can approve the answers, so everyone can see that at least this answer was the solution for this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code for the handleKeyDown function; A single function with proper conditional statements can handle right and left arrow navigation. Note that I've set the conditionals up so that they won't trigger if the slide.index value is 0 (for prevSlide) or non-existent (nextSlide).

```
handleKeyDown = (event) => {
  if(event.keyCode === 39 && this.state.slide.index !== data.inferno.length-1 ){
    this.nextSlide();
  } else if(event.keyCode === 37 && this.state.slide.index !== 0){
    this.prevSlide();
  }
}

...

<div className="buttons" onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
```